# Recreating php from Vue.js, Express.js and SQL db

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, express, web-development-server

I am picking up a project from someone else. As of now all the front end and server code as well as the SQL for the database is with me but I have none of the PHP files.
I was wondering if there's any way I can use the code I have on hand as a reference to recreate those missing PHP files or is all my code just useless?

Comment: I'm not clear what it means to have "all the server code", but "none of the PHP files", since in a PHP application, the PHP files would _be_ the server code. So, it kind of depends what the missing PHP files did, and what exactly you have. In general, though, the answer is "no" - there could be thousands of lines of application code which you're missing, and you would have no way whatsoever to know what they did. That doesn't mean the code you have is _useless_ though - you could use the database and front-end as the starting point for a new project.

Comment: My bad, by server code I meant I have the express routes that they built. I have none of the PHP files. Anyway, since the answer is no, how would I go about using the stuff that I do have as a starting point to recreate this project?

Comment: There isn't going to be any one answer to that. Imagine someone gave you some cushions, and a pile of springs and bolts, and said they used to be part of an armchair. You can't use them to recreate the _same_ armchair, but if you're making a new armchair, you might decide to re-use some of those parts - or you might decide that the springs are the wrong size, and the cushions are a horrible colour, and you'd rather start again. Either way, you have to work out how to make an armchair.